# open the file instead of the link and not to download

Tags: html, css

In my HTML I have created a link to a .pdf file outside and I wish that when I click on the word of my link would open automatically the file and not to ask me to download the file link.
It can do this ????

The link I created and this:

```
<a href="file.pdf">Nome link</a>
```

Comment: This is not a question of the reference you write. It depends on two things: 1. the user settings inside the browser (nothing you can change) and 2. the implementation on the http server delivering the file (nothing you can change in your case, since you claim it is "outside").

Comment: I would like to do that when I click on the link opens the file and just. You should not have any choice

Comment: Yes, you wrote that. Why do you repeat it here in the comments? It is not that we did not understand the question. Did _you_ understand my comment?

Comment: Try `window.open('file.pdf', '_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to force a user to open a file directly from the web using standard HTML.

This is something the browser chooses. Chrome always downloads, for instance. Firefox and IE may download, save to a temp folder, and then "open" the downloaded temp copy. But in those browsers the user always has a choice.

NOTE: You can actually go the other way - force a download instead of letting the browser open it - by using HTTP headers.

Comment: 1. this is configurable in all browsers and 2. you cannot sent headers for a link to an object delivered from another host which is what the OP does.

Comment: You're right about the 2nd point. I missed the PDF being on a 3rd party server. I'm this case headers cannot be edited. Regarding the browser configure though, no not *all* browsers even let the user configure that. Regardless, it's something the author has no control over.

Comment: How do you see the PDF file is on another host? In the OP's example, it's in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

When the file is downloaded you can choose options and then select always open this kind of files.

Works in Edge and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

When thé link the description is download toi Can choose options and then select Always open this if files.

Works un effet and chrome